# JavaScript code won't work on some browsers

Tags: javascript, html

I created code that will work same as facebook add friends to send message list ( filed To: ).
Code is created in FrontPage, also it's tested there, with limited functions, as FrontPage preview is, and it's working...
Then it's tested in IE 7 and IE 8 and even IE 9, and it also works...
Also tested in FireFox, Chrome and Safari, and it's working also...

Then, I send this code to friend, and he said it's not working...
I'm looking over code all over again and again, and I can't find what can be wrong...

Code info:

topolje - div that contains list of users, and when you click on specific user it call function addnewto('username')

howbig - background div that counts size of new created user field, so input field can be resized to fit field where is list of users and input...

newone - input where you start typing username and it shows down usernames that start with that...

getRefToDiv(id_of_element) - find element by it's id in different browsers

Here is code:

```
var skup = new Array();
var skup2 = new Array();

function addnewto(user)
{

var i = 777777;
var userform = '';
var k = 0;
var velicina = 23;
getRefToDiv('topolje').style.height = "23px";

for ( j = 0; j < skup.length; j++ ) {
if ( skup[j] == "" ) {
i = j;
}
else
{

userform2 = '<font id="tekst' + j + '" name="tekst' + j + '" style="background: #8BBC40; border:1px solid #808080; -moz-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px; padding-left:4px; padding-right:4px; padding-top:1px; padding-bottom:1px" face="Tahoma" size="2" color="#FFFFFF">' + skup2[j] + ' |<span onclick="';
userform2 += "this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(getRefToDiv('tekst" + j + "-1')); this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode); skup.splice(" + j + ",1); skup2.splice(" + j + ",1); setTimeout('getsize();', 10);;";
userform2 += '" style="cursor: pointer"> x </span></font><span id="tekst' + j + '-1" name="tekst' + j + '-1">&nbsp;</span>';


var mast = getRefToDiv('howbig');
var duzina = 0;
mast.innerHTML = userform + userform2;
duzina = mast.clientWidth;

if ( duzina > 405 ) {
userform += "<br>" + userform2;
velicina += 21;
getRefToDiv('topolje').style.height = velicina + "px";
}
else
{
userform += userform2;
}

}
}

if ( i = 777777 ) {
i = skup.length;
}

skup[i] = 'tekst' + i;
skup2[i] = user;


userform2 = '<font id="tekst' + i + '" name="tekst' + i + '" style="background: #8BBC40; border:1px solid #808080; -moz-border-radius: 2px; border-radius: 2px; padding-left:4px; padding-right:4px; padding-top:1px; padding-bottom:1px" face="Tahoma" size="2" color="#FFFFFF">' + user + ' |<span onclick="';
userform2 += "this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(getRefToDiv('tekst" + i + "-1')); this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode); skup.splice(" + i + ",1); skup2.splice(" + i + ",1); setTimeout('getsize();', 10);";
userform2 += '" style="cursor: pointer"> x </span></font><span id="tekst' + i + '-1" name="tekst' + i + '-1">&nbsp;</span>';


var mast = getRefToDiv('howbig');
var duzina = 0;
mast.innerHTML = userform + userform2;
duzina = mast.clientWidth;

if ( duzina > 405 ) {
userform += "<br>" + userform2;
velicina += 21;
getRefToDiv('topolje').style.height = velicina + "px";
}
else
{
userform += userform2;
}



getRefToDiv('topolje').innerHTML = userform + '<input type="text" onblur="if ( this.value.length < 3 ) { proveri(0); } else { proveri(2); }" onfocus="if ( this.value.length < 2 ) { proveri(1); }" onkeyup="if ( this.value.length > 2 ) { proveri(this.value); }" style="border: 1px solid #FFFFFF; width: 10px; font-family:Verdana; font-size:10pt; color:#8BBC40;" id="newone" name="newone">';

reorder();
}


function reorder()
{

var i = 777777;
var userform = '';
var userformx = '';
var k = 0;
var velicina = 23;
getRefToDiv('topolje').style.height = "23px";


for ( j = 0; j < skup.length; j++ ) {
if ( skup[j] == "" ) {
i = j;
}
else
{

userform2 = '<font id="tekst' + j + '" name="tekst' + j + '" style="background: #8BBC40; border:1px solid #808080; -moz-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px; padding-left:4px; padding-right:4px; padding-top:1px; padding-bottom:1px" face="Tahoma" size="2" color="#FFFFFF">' + skup2[j] + ' |<span onclick="';
userform2 += "this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(getRefToDiv('tekst" + j + "-1')); this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode); skup.splice(" + j + ",1); skup2.splice(" + j + ",1); setTimeout('getsize();', 10);;";
userform2 += '" style="cursor: pointer"> x </span></font><span id="tekst' + j + '-1" name="tekst' + j + '-1">&nbsp;</span>';


var mast = getRefToDiv('howbig');
var duzina = 0;
mast.innerHTML = userform + userform2;
duzina = mast.clientWidth;

if ( duzina > 405 ) {
userform += "<br>" + userform2;
userformx = userform2;
velicina += 21;
getRefToDiv('topolje').style.height = velicina + "px";
}
else
{
userform += userform2;
userformx += userform2;
}

}
}

getRefToDiv('topolje').innerHTML = userform + '<input type="text" onblur="if ( this.value.length < 3 ) { proveri(0); } else { proveri(2); }" onfocus="if ( this.value.length < 2 ) { proveri(1); }" onkeyup="if ( this.value.length > 2 ) { proveri(this.value); } else  { proveri(1); }" style="border: 1px solid #FFFFFF; width: 10px; font-family:Verdana; font-size:10pt; color:#8BBC40;" id="newone" name="newone">';


var mast = getRefToDiv('howbig');
var duzina = 0;

mast.innerHTML = userformx;
duzina += mast.clientWidth;
var duzina2 = 400 - duzina;
getRefToDiv('newone').style.width = duzina2 + 'px';



}
```

I'm working on this for very long time, and I can't figure this out...
If you find something that can be wrong, please tell me...

Thanks.

Comment: Steps to solve your problem:  1. Go here:  http://jslint.com/  2. Paste your code in the box.  3. Click on "The Good Parts" below, then click on the "JSLint" link.  4. Cry.  5. Then try to fix all the problems.  6. Rejoice!

Comment: Even after disabling the "Strict Whitespace" parameter, I got this far: "Problem at line 79 character 17: Too many errors. (58% scanned)."

Comment: does frontpage support intending?

Comment: Little-known fact: every once in a while, when you hit the space bar a really delicious piece of candy pops out of your keyboard. You never know when it'll happen, so keep indenting!  (Seriously, that candy is **awesome**.)

Comment: @Matt, I like the literal interpretation of @meo's comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't even know how this works in any browser.

This:

```
if ( i = 777777 ) {
i = skup.length;
}
```

should be this:

```
if (i === 777777) {
    i = skup.length;
}
```

This is a common bug in code referred to as "Accidental Assignment." That is, unless you ALWAYS want the conditional block to evaluate true, in which case your code is equivalent to:

```
i = 777777;
i = skup.length;
```

Which I'm sure you don't mean.  I would recommend switching away from a WYSIWYG editor in favor of a good IDE that would point these things out to you (NetBeans, for example, highlighted this line for me as soon as I pasted your code into a new blank javascript file).

And, that is just one issue of many.  See my comment on the question for instructions for solving all of the other problems.

Comment: Good catch.  To answer your question, it "works" because the result of `i = 777777` is `777777` which is truthy.  Good lint tools (JSLint, closure compiler, the caja linter) should all catch this.

Comment: @Mike, I pointed that out in the following commentary, re: "unless you ALWAYS want the conditional block to evaluate true..."  by "works" I meant, "does what you intend it to do."

Comment: sorry.  My rhetorical question detector doesn't always "work."

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in line 217 and line 42